# Mutliline TextInput with ScrollsToTop in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to have a "scroll to top" action on multiline TextInput when the user taps the status bar on iOS. TextInput has a maximum scale in the screen so that the context is fairly straight.

```js
<TextInput multiline={true} scrollsToTop={true} />
```

However, `RCTMultilineTextInputView` has `backedTextInputView` as a subview and the props doesn't pass to the subview. ([It's hardcoded](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Text/TextInput/Multiline/RCTMultilineTextInputView.m#L32) as `NO`)

Is there any way I can pass this prop? Or, is there any better implementation for this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an additional property `scrollsToTop` via category.

```
// RCTMultilineTextInputView+ScrollsToTopAdditions.h

#import "RCTText/RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager.h"
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager (ScrollsToTopAdditions)

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```
// RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager+ScrollsToTopAdditions.m

#import "RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager+ScrollsToTopAdditions.h"

@implementation RCTMultilineTextInputViewManager (ScrollsToTopAdditions)
#if !TARGET_OS_TV
  RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(scrollsToTop, backedTextInputView.scrollsToTop, BOOL)
#endif
@end
```